# Determining time complexity of a function

Tags: python, optimization, hash

I have a computer science project in which i am tasked to assess the time complexity of this specific function and also figure out a way to optimize it by using hash function data structures like sets and dictionaries.

```
def uber_friends(group, network, current_user):        
    if  current_user not in group:                 
        group.append(current_user)
        for x in range(0, len(network)):
            if current_user in network[x]:
                ind = network[x].index(current_user)  
                if ind == 0:
                    uber_friends(group, network, network[x][1])
                if ind == 1:
                    uber_friends(group,network, network[x][0])
    else:
        return None

    return group
```

For clarification "group" is supposed to be an empty list at first, network is supposed to be a nested list in which the elements inside the inner lists are 2 ints and current_user is supposed to be an int
Edit: typo

Comment: Please check your code. Is `grumo` a typo?

Comment: I think the problem boils down to finding all your friends which have you as one of their top 2. So in that case, the best time complexity will be `O(N^2)` where N is the size of the `network` list. Assuming the above algorithm is acting optimially, then the answer should be `O(N^2)`

Comment: Correction, if we also take into account the `if current_user in network[x]:`, then the time complexity would be `O(MN^2)` where `M` is worst-case size of each friend's network

Answer (score 2):

A good first step in figuring out the time complexity of a function is to run it with some sample input -- we can then trace through the function and see where the execution might be spending its time.

```
uber_friends([], [], 1)
```

```
    uber_friends([], [], 1)
  File "test.py", line 2, in uber_friends
    if current_user not in grumo:
NameError: name 'grumo' is not defined
```

This exception is raised on the first line of the function, and will be raised regardless of what parameters are passed.  The time complexity of the function is therefore O(1).

We could simplify the implementation down to a single line that behaves the same as the original recursive function:

```
def uber_friends(group, network, current_user):
    raise NameError("name 'grumo' is not defined")
```

but this does not affect the time complexity.  Further optimization involving different data structures is neither possible nor necessary.

Comment: I figured `grumo` was a typo. But that's a hilarious assignment if the teacher was actually looking for constant time complexity.

Comment: Never assume anything in a CS assignment is a typo -- the interpreter/compiler certainly won't!

Comment: Loving this analysis. Assuming `grumo` is not a typo

Comment: nb: we could also just replace the function body with the single statement `grumo` and get the same result, but IMO it's better for the optimized version to clearly express the intent.

Comment: Yeah sorry guys, grumo is definetly a typo, thanks for your help anyways